# How to rearrange chat table while in live chat on scringo chat app?

Tags: ios, livechat, scringo

I  am developing a chat app using Scringo SDk, it is all fine, but there is a problem in one to one live chat that is new message comes on the top so i need to scroll to top in all messages to see new message, or need to press the back button in navigation and come back to that chat view, then it is automatically arranged perfectly. I also not able to access that tableView to manually rearrange the messages. Please suggest me a way to solve this problem.

Screen shots are as:-

[image]

[image]